# Button Border in CSS

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the image, when I click the search button on the right  there is an orange border, and I would like to remove it. I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
.btn-serch:active{
    background-color: #92949C;
    border:0px solid white;
}
```

I also tried:

```
.btn-serch:active{
    background-color: #92949C;
    border:none;
}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.btn-serch:active{
    background-color: #92949C;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
   }
```

OR

```
button:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: it's work perfectly thanks

Comment: Nice to hear :) Mark the answer as accepted Please :)

Comment: done , thanks one more time :D

Comment: Ya i see :) Welcome my pleasure :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to override the [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property

Comment: thanks, friend I forget  about the outline